# I can not send data to the api by httppost via Ajax

Tags: ajax, api

if i type controler and action data in url send corectly,but when want to send data to api data data send zero to method parameter

```
 var urll = 'https://localhost:44337/api/apiialbums/GetAlbum';  
 $.ajax({
                
                type: "post",               
                url: urll, error: function () { alert("errore") },
                data:{id:25,x:2},
                success: function (dataa) {
                    alert("okk");
}
});
```

> my api class code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Album>> GetAlbum(int id,int x)
        {
            var album = await _context.Albums.FindAsync(id);

            if (album == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return album;    
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use [FromForm] for method parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Album>> GetAlbum([FromForm] int id,[FromForm] int x)
        {
            var album = await _context.Albums.FindAsync(id);

            if (album == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return album;    
        }
```

default is [FromQuery].the [FromQuery] Causes the parameter value to be read from the url, but [FromForm] causes the value to be read from data:{id:25,x:2} in ajax code